# How to .Scan() a MySQL TIMESTAMP value into a time.Time variable?

Tags: mysql, go

I have this Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "time"
)

type User struct {
    id                  uint32
    name                string
    email               string
    rating              uint8
    subscription        uint8
    date_registered     time.Time
    online              string
}

// main entry point
func main() {
    // setup db connection
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/c9?parseTime=true")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // query
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", 1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    usr := User{}
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&usr.id, &usr.name, &usr.email, &usr.rating, &usr.subscription, &usr.date_registered, &usr.online)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(usr)
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

This is what I get from MySQL console:

```
mysql> describe users;
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| email           | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| rating          | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| subscription    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| date_registered | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| online          | char(1)             | NO   |     | N                 |                |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
| id | name       | email                 | rating | subscription | date_registered     | online |
+----+------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | alakhazamm | abcdefghhhh@gmail.com |   NULL |            0 | 2014-10-28 15:37:44 | N      |
+----+------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

After `.Scan()`, `fmt.Println(usr)` prints

```
{1 alakhazamm abcdefghhhh@gmail.com 0 0 {0 0 <nil>} }
```

The last two fields of the struct are wrong but I have no idea why.
I've tried using `date_registered string` in the struct definition, but I get an empty string after `.Scan()`.
I've also read in the driver's docs that `?parseTime=true` parses MySQL DATE and DATETIME values into time.Time, but they don't mention TIMESTAMP which is what I'm currently using.

Am I missing something important or is it a bug/missing feature of the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the cause of the error.

Since `rating` is NULL in the database, the scanner gave the error

> sql: Scan error on column index 3: converting string "nil" to a
>   uint8: strconv.ParseUint: parsing "nil": invalid syntax

I've updated the database row and now `usr.date_registered` and `usr.online` hold the correct values.

I guess I'll have to make the MySQL field NOT NULL and just use -1 to indicate a non-initialised value.

Comment: You can scan possibly null ints using NullInt64 type in database/sql package. http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64

Comment: We have so many time stamps in our code that can be null, that we ended up just adding a simple NullTime class that is modeled the same as the other DB null classes.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old question however I was missing this parameter in my Open call:

```
parseTime=true
```

[See here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support)

Answer (score 13):

In addition to answer by @incognick, here is exactly you can do (add parseTime=true):

```
db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "myuser:mypass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb?parseTime=true")
```

If there is a possibility of timestamp/datetime be null, in that case you should use scan parameter as sql.NullTime instead of time.Time.

Using sql.NullTime will provide you option to check if scanned time is null or not using `var.Valid` flag. You can use time with `var.Time` if it is valid and not null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you can do

```
    var hourStartedAt string = ""
    var hourStartedAtTime *time.Time

    apiQuery := "SELECT hour_started_at from developer_api WHERE apikey = ?"
    apiQueryResult, apiQueryError := db.ConnRead.Query(apiQuery, apiKey, apiSecret)

    if apiQueryResult.Next() {

      apiQueryResult.Scan(&hourStartedAt)
      hourStartedAtTime = StringToDate(hourStartedAt)

    }


func StringToDate(date string) *time.Time {
    parsed, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", date)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return &parsed
}
```